# Input a number and return day of week

Tags: code-golf, string

Not restricted to any one programming language.

What I'm saying is you pass 1 to it and it returns Monday, 7 corresponds with sunday and so on.

I've managed a 146 byte statement in Java to do the same.

```
return (n<1?"invalid":(n<2?"monday":(n<3?"tuesday":(n<4?"wednesday":(n<5?"thursday":(n<6?"friday":(n<7?"saturday":(n<8?"sunday":"invalid"))))))));
```

Your program should:

- output full words (STDOUT)
- not crash if the input is less than 1 or greater than 7

Comment: updated tags. my bad! i've kept it as a popularity contest, as open-platform code-golf ends up being one language versus the other more than one logic versus the other. Most upvotes (thus most recognition and appreciation for logic) wins.

Comment: have I been downvoted as a sign of disappointment in my question, or my code?

Comment: my bad, again. first question, sorry.

Comment: I can't know what other people are downvoting for, but I would expect people to dislike the use of "popularity contest" on a question that is purely a golf question. Generally popularity contest is used for questions that don't have an objective way of deciding a winner.

Comment: will keep in mind. I wasn't aware of the setting guidelines.

Comment: This question can't agree with itself on what it wants people to write. A statement which finds input in a variable and returns it or a program which writes to stdout? (It's also a bizarre use of [tag:popularity-contest] which, if it catches on, might do a lot to help those who want to kill the tag completely).

Comment: You'll learn what works and what makes a good question by asking questions just like you are, and getting feedback. I personally thought this question was too simple to make an interesting challenge, but you have 3 answers already in just half an hour, which shows that it's hard to guess what makes a good challenge until you ask it. With the new reputation you gain from this question you'll soon be able to use the [sandbox](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/1847/proposed-question-sandbox-mark-xiv?cb=1) to get feedback on ideas before you post them.

Comment: Note that questions are language agnostic by default - you don't need to specify that it's not restricted to one programming language.

Comment: @peter-taylor that was not my intention.

Comment: Why answering yourself in your question? That's a pity for those who want to search a clever solution by themselves. You can add an answer of your own instead!

Comment: @Blackhole it's a reference implementation. Much larger than a winning golf entry, so it's not really preventing anyone from being clever. It is, however, providing precise output examples for all input cases.

Comment: The question says you should output to stdout, but the accepted answer doesn't do so and even assumes the existence of a variable. Also, do we **have** to output `invalid` if the input is invalid? The question doesn't state that but the example suggests so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Ruby, 69 or 38 bytes

Here is a simple way to improve your code (written in Ruby but it works similarly in Java):

```
n>0&&n<8?%w{Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun}[n-1]+"day":"Invalid"
```

- Combine the two invalid checks into one.
- Put all the days in an array and use `n` as an index.
- Factor out the common `day`.

You can make it even shorter if you import the names of the days of the week from a library, like Ruby's:

```
n>0&&n<8?Date::DAYNAMES[n%7]:"Invalid"
```

Note that now I don't decrement `n` but instead take it modulo 7 to map `7` to `0`. This is because `DAYNAMES` starts with Sunday.

Comment: Gah, I was just about to put a Lua version of this same thing (except it was going to be about 100 characters longer)...

Comment: damn, I wasn't thinking on the lines of arrays at all. I had gotten so caught up in ternary, that I hadn't realized I could merge the two. amazing!

Comment: Can you do n>0&n<8 (removing the second &) in Ruby?
I know that works in Java.

Comment: @bmarks It looks like you can't due it due to precedence, at least before Ruby 2.0 (I don't have a Ruby 2.x interpreter here right now).

Comment: [21 in Rebmu](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36341/57) ... :-)

Answer (score 9):

### Bash: 47 bytes

Still no bash entry? I'm disappointed ...

```
case $1 in
    [1-7]) date -d "14-08-1$1" +%A
esac
```

It uses the days of the current week and simply substitutes the last digit (11-17 August 2014 -- 11 is Monday, 12 is Tuesday, etc.).

Comment: Wow, what a clever solution! Hard coding a date for this is brilliant!. Is there no way for the date format to accept just '8' as the month? And then you can find a month/year pair where the first is a monday.

Comment: Thanks! `date -d $1sept +%A` works as well (though only this year; reduces bytes to 6*9). GNU `date` is really flexible in that matter so there should be additional possibilities.

Comment: If you post this as an answer for `date` rather than Bash, it would be a mere `14-08-1$1` – 9 bytes!

Comment: It's 46 bytes, don't count the trailing newline;

Comment: Well, more than 2 times shorter version :): http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36424/11887 .

Answer (score 6):

### Javascript, <strike>95</strike> 88 bytes

```
x=prompt();alert("Invalid 0Mon0Tue0Wednes0Thurs0Fri0Satur0Sun".split(0)[x&~7?0:x]+"day")
```

7 in binary is 0111, meaning that you can shave off a few characters with a bitwise operation instead of `x>0&&x<8`.

Edit: Removed the `s` array with the help of [edc65](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/21348/edc65).

Comment: that's a neat method!

Comment: Neat method indeed. 1) I count 95 bytes, not 97. 2) You don't need ad s variable and can do 88:`x=prompt();alert("Invalid 0Mon0Tue0Wednes0Thurs0Fri0Satur0Sun".split(0)[x&~7?0:x]+"day")`

Comment: Ah, that's clever! I'll update my post now.

Answer (score 6):

## [Marbelous](https://github.com/marbelous-lang/marbelous.py) <strike>192</strike> <strike>191</strike> <strike>185</strike> 181

```
}0
=1=2=3=4=5=6=7--
&1&2&3&4&5&6&7{0
&8////////////
4D6F6E547565735765646E65735468757273467269536174757253756E646179
&1&1&1&2&2&2&2&3&3&3&3&3&3&4&4&4&4&4&5&5&5&6&6&6&6&6&7&7&7&8&8&8
```

Non-zero exit code if the input is invalid

Usage:

```
# marbelous.py -r day-of-week.mbl 2
Tuesday
```

Answer (score 5):

### C# - 26 Bytes

Expects the day to be stored inside `n`. 
Does not crash, as expected. 
Powered by LINQPad™

```c#
((DayOfWeek)(n%7)).Dump();
```

<sub>Special thanks to bmarks and  Stephan Schinkel for byte saving and rule bending, respectively</sub>

Comment: Can you remove the second & in the conditional? I don't think short circuit evaluation here is necessary.

Comment: @bmarks You're correct, thanks

Comment: The Question does not mentione to return "Invalid" it just states the program should not crash. So you could write return ((DayOfWeek)(i%7)).ToString(); (37 chars)

Comment: @StephanSchinkel Yeah, I guess you're right

Answer (score 2):

### C#, 95 bytes

In C# you can do something like this:

```
return(i>7||i<0)?"invalid":new[]{"mon","tues","wednes","thurs","fri","satur","sun"}[i-1]+"day";
```

Comment: There is an error in the bounds checking, you need to be checking that `i<1`, and you can save 2 bytes by using `|` rather than `||` (not short-circuiting) and removing the brackets around the condition. It's also shorter to create and split a string thus `" mon tues wednes thurs fri satur sun".Split()[i]` than to create an array of string of this size (note the space at the start of the string, which saves subtracting 1 from i)

Answer (score 2):

## Javascript 93 :(

```
q=prompt();alert(q<8&&q>0?'0mon0tues0wednes0thurs0fri0satur0sun'.split(0)[q]+'day':'invalid')
```

Comment: why exactly have you used q&&q<8 ?

Comment: q&&qq<8 checks if q is between 1 and 7

Comment: What if `q` is `-5`?

Comment: :( but thats an extra 2 bytes for >0. Fixed using ipi's bit trick, also saves 2 bytes

Comment: Does it work with q == 0?

Comment: @edc65 fixed :(

Answer (score 2):

### T-SQL 36

```
SELECT DATENAME(w,@+6)WHERE(6+@)/7=1
```

Assumes the variable is stored in @. If it is an invalid input (@>7 or @<1), then it doesn't select anything.

Edit: Apparently a date can be a number. Removed 5 characters with that.

Edit 2: Based on the first edit. Since it's an int, I don't have to use DATEADD(); I can use normal addition instead.

Answer (score 2):

## [Extended BrainFuck](http://sylwester.no/ebf/): 104

```
{a))<(->>}+>,49-(-(-(-(-(-((-)<->>|"sun")<(->>|"satur"&a|"fri"&a|"thurs"&a|"wednes"&a|"tues"&a|"mon")|"day"
```

Ungolfed (Idiomatic)

```
{main 
  :flag +
  :input
 
  $input &read_number -
  (-
   (-
    (-
     (-
      (-
       (        $input &reset  ; 7-9
                $flag  &reset
                |"sun" &reset )
                
        $flag ( &reset         ; 6 
                |"satur" &reset  ))
                
       $flag (  &reset         ; 5
                |"fri" &reset    ))
                
      $flag (   &reset         ; 4
                |"thurs" &reset  ))
                
     $flag (    &reset         ; 3
                |"wednes" &reset ))
                
    $flag (     &reset         ; 2
                |"tues" &reset   ))
                
   $flag (      &reset         ; 1
                |"mon" &reset    )

   |"day"
}
{reset (-)}
{read_number , 48- }

;; call main
&main
```

Answer (score 2):

## Mathematica <s>19</s> 16 bytes

```
DayName@{1,1,#}&
```

As Dr. Rebmu noted, January 1, 1 A.D. is a good place to start.  It (presumably) fell on a Monday.

```
    DayName@{2014, 9, #} &[1]
```

> Monday

Comment: Why September of 2014 and not [January 1st year 1 AD](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=day+of+week+January+1st+1)?

Comment: The answer is: I failed to think of it.  But I will incorporate your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

## Lua - 57 bytes

```
print(n>0 and n<8 and os.date("%A",9e4*(n+3))or"Invalid")
```

Lua has os.date() in it's standard library, and it has formatting. So you can pass a time (in this case "9e4*(n+3)") and ask to return the "%A" format, which is the names of the days of the week.
Also, very useful in Lua is "a and b or c". If a is true (in the code a is "n>0 and n<8") it returns b, if a is false (or nil) it returns c.

Comment: Can you provide an explanation?

Comment: The OP specifically asked for error handling, although it was pretty vague. Next time, ask for clarification before posting an incomplete answer.

Comment: I don't think the space after `%A` is necessary

Comment: @KyleKanos Right you are. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

## Bash - <strike>21</strike> 19

Assuming the input is in variable `D`:

```
date +%A -d$D"Jan1"
```

## HTML + PHP - 26

Let `$d` be an input text

```
<?=date('l',86400*(3+$d));
```

Timestamp 86400*3 is the first Sunday from the start of UNIX world.

You can test it by executing:

```
<?php $d=3; ?>
<?=date('l',86400*(3+$d));
```

Answer (score 1):

## Lua <s>134</s> <s>119</s> <s>115</s> <s>100</s> 98

```
q={"mon","tues","wednes","thurs","fri","satur","sun"}print(n<8 and n>0 and q[n].."day"or"invalid")
```

Basically the same thought [MartinButtner](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36221/11376) had, except about <s>4.5</s> <s>4.1</s> <s>1.7</s> 1.4 times longer. Does assume `n` is stored as a variable elsewhere.

Comment: In fairness, you don't need any of that I/O here.

Comment: @MartinBüttner: I think it's longer if I use a function

Comment: Just expect `n` to be stored in a variable, as in the OP's snippet.

Comment: yeah, I wasn't expecting any I/O on your side.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 60 bytes

Something like this:

```
$x&&qw{Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun}[$x-1]."day"||die
```

If want to return a message instead and you're concerned about negative indexes you can use this one instead (8 more chars):

```
$x>0&&qw{Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun}[$x-1]."day"||"Invalid"
```

Answer (score 1):

### Bash <strike>74</strike> 48 + error message

A different approach since all other answers focus on storing the strings in some form.

```
read x;((0<x&&x<8))&&date -d2007010$x +%A||echo out of range
```

Comment: what is the byte count?

Comment: @proudhaskeller Irrelevant as this has not been tagged as [tag:code-golf]

Comment: you're right, just all other solutions have a byte count. weird.

Comment: That is more a POSIX `sh` answer. In `bash` you can use arithmetic evaluation. `read x;((0<x&&x<8))&&date -d2007010$x +%A||echo out of range` is shorter.

Comment: The question only stated that the program should not crash in case the number is not between 1 and 7, so you can just remove the `||echo out of range`. Considering that the accepted solution doesn't follow the rules (print to stdout)... But if you want to follow the OP's example, you can use `invalid` instead of `out of range`.

Answer (score 1):

## Python (84)

```
lambda a:'imtwtfssnouehrauvneduitnadsnrdudladesaraiyasdydyd yda a    ay y    y'[a if 0<a<8 else 0::8]
```

I suppose it's an interesting sollution. It takes an idea from another answere I read somewhere (can't find it, I do know it was on this site, so if anyone knows feel free to tell me.)
The string was generated with the following J program:

```
,|:>'invalid';'monday';'tuesday';'wednesday';'thursday';'friday';'saturday';'sunday'
```

Taking some subtle hints from [this](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/36227/18638) answer:

```
lambda a:' mtwtfssouehrauneduitn snr u   es r   s'[a::7]+'day'if 0<a<8 else'invalid'
```

Answer (score 1):

## Befunge-93 (206 <s>208</s>)

This one was fun to write. I'm sure it can be done in a better way, but… it works! =)
Can be tried out [here](http://www.bedroomlan.org/tools/befunge-93-playground).

Would've been even shorter if the `#` would jump over entire strings rather than just the individual cell.

```
&1-    v
vv"Mon"># :# !_
> 1-    v
vv"Tues"># :# !_
> 1-      v
vv"Wednes"># :# !_
> 1-     v
vv"Thurs"># :# !_
> 1-   v
vv"Fri"># :# !_
> 1-     v
vv"Satur"># :# !_
> 1-   v
vv"Sun"># :# !_
>>:#,_"yad",,,@
```

The basic idea behind it: Get the number and keep decrementing it. Everytime we decrement it, the cursor moves to the right, wraps around and is sent one level lower. Once we hit zero, move to the left instead and push the (first part of the) day name. From then on, the cursor will move straight to the bottom where the string is printed and "day" is appended.

You can see how it works by using the "Step" feature in the link to the online interpreter.

*Edit:* I managed to shave two bytes off by doing `>:#,_` instead of `>,,,,,,`, which is pretter as well.

Answer (score 1):

### Clojure - 99 chars

Plain and simple, despite my best (newbie) attempts:

```
(defn f[x](get{1"monday"2"tuesday"3"wednesday"4"thursday"5"friday"6"saturday"7"sunday"}x"invalid"))
```

Answer (score 1):

## Perl, 54

From STDIN to STDOUT, no date functions, no crash.

```
print((a,Mon,Tues,Wednes,Thurs,Fri,Satur,Sun)[<>].day)
```

Answer (score 1):

## JS: 58

Assuming n is already stored as a variable.

```
"0Mon0Tues0Wednes0Thurs0Fri0Satur0Sun".split(0)[n%8]+"day"
```

As an ES6 function (same assumptions): **67**

```
let d=n=>"0Mon0Tues0Wednes0Thurs0Fri0Satur0Sun".split(0)[n%8]+"day"
```

This will just print "day" for 0 and loops around for n > 7

Comment: "Tueday"? Also, your description is inaccurate, it returns `day` for `8` and starts again from `Monday` at `9`.

Comment: @nyuszika7h Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 1):

## Haskell - 62

Wraps around; `0` is Sunday, `8` is Monday, and so on.

```
words"Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun"!!(mod(n-1)7)++"day"
```

If printing to stdout is required (**68 bytes**, output is in double quotes):

```
print$words"Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun"!!(mod(n-1)7)++"day"
```

Answer (score 1):

## **MATLAB : 33**

```
datestr(3:9,'dddd');ans(1:7==n,:)
```

## **MATLAB : 71**

```
{'mon';'tues';'wednes';'thurs';'fri';'satur';'sun'};[ans{1:7==2} 'day']
```

## **Haskell : 75**

```
g n=((++"day").last.take(abs n).words)"mon tues wednes thurs fri satur sun"
```

## **Haskell : 97**

```
f n=if elem n[1..7]then["mon","tues","wednes","thurs","fri","satur","sun"]!!n++"day"else"invalid"
```

## **Python 3.4.1 : 81**

```
'invalid mon tues wednes thurs fri satur sun'.split(' ')[n*(n in range(8))]+'day'
```

Comment: You probably should post these as separate answers.

Comment: In Python: `(0<n<8)` is shorter then `(n in range(8))`. `split()` also split string

Answer (score 1):

## PHP (56 bytes)

```
$d=1;echo$d>0&&$d<8?date('D',255600+$d*86400):'Invalid';
```

Answer (score 1):

## LiveScript - 49

Returns `undefinedday` if the input is invalid. ;)

```
<[Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun]>[n-1]+\day
```

If printing to stdout is required (**60 bytes**):

```
console.log<[Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun]>[n-1]+\day
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Rebmu](https://github.com/hostilefork/rebmu): 21 characters

```
pcSYSTEM/locale/daysA
```

To run:

```
>> rebmu/args {pcSYSTEM/locale/daysA} 1 
== "Monday"
```

Invalid numbers will return "none".

```
>> rebmu/args {pcSYSTEM/locale/daysA} 8 
== none

>> rebmu/args {pcSYSTEM/locale/daysA} 0
== none
```

For those unfamiliar with Rebmu, it uses case transitions to remove the need for spacing--within the limits of what's legally parseable.  Rather than using a InitialCapsToBreak it uses CASEtransitionsTObreak, because that allows a different meaning to be ascribed to an initial run of capitals from if the initial initial run is lowercase.

So it is equivalent to the Rebol program `pick system/locale/days a`.  (Rebmu by convention names its script parameter as "a").

Saves one character over `system/locale/days/(a)` :-)

Answer (score 1):

### Java 8 - <strike>69</strike> 64 chars

Here's an expression in Java 8, including the import. Now improved (thanks to [Tomáš Dvořák](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/26993/tom%C3%A1%C5%A1-dvo%C5%99%C3%A1k)):

```
import java.time.*;
return DayOfWeek.of((i>0&i<8)?i:1).name();
```

Simply prints `MONDAY` for bogus values of `i`

Comment: Tip: .name() is shorter than .toString() and does the same thing. You can save 4 characters. Also you can use only one & instead of two and save another char.

Answer (score 1):

## Python - 87

I'm not seeing enough love for dict's .get()
This one expects `a` to be the number

```
dict(enumerate("mon,tues,wednes,thurs,fri,satur,sun".split(","),1)).get(a,"bad ")+"day"
```

Comment: You can save some characters by removing all occurrences of `day` in your list and add `+"day"` at the end of your code.

Comment: You can also save some characters by putting all days in one string and then split them instead of putting them all separately in the list: `"mon,tues,...".split(",")`

Comment: That works nicely, cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Python, 95 bytes

```
"%day"%["mon","tues","wednes","thurs","fri","satur","sun"][n-1] if 0<n<8 else "invalid"
```

Comment: monsday? Did I read that right?

Comment: Not sure where you got 95 bytes from, by my count it's 88. I managed to save 11 by fixing the "monsday" bug, using string concatenation instead of `%` formatting, creating the list from a string using `split()` and removing unnecessary whitespace.

Comment: `"mon tues wednes thurs fri satur sun".split()[n-1]+"day"if 0<n<8else"invalid"`

Comment: @undergroundmonorail you can save another 6 bytes by using single quotes instead of double quotes

Comment: @githubphagocyte I can't tell if you're joking or seriously mistaken regarding how many bytes quote characters take up.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail I was making a very poor joke.

Comment: @undergroundmonorail 87, actually. Don't count the trailing newline.

Comment: @nyuszika7h that comment was before githubphagocyte's edit

Answer (score 0):

## Python 2, <s>84</s> <s>83</s> 64

Assuming n is already stored as a variable.

```
import calendar as c;print c.day_name[n-1]if 0<n<8 else'Invalid'
```

Comment: [From this comment](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/36218/popularity-contest-shortest-possible-algorithm-to-input-a-number-and-return-day#comment79951_36222), it does seem like input can be ignored.

Answer (score 0):

## Golfscript (50 <s>55</s>)

Expects the input number to be on the stack.

```
" Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun"" "/\="day"+
```

or

```
("Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun"" "/\="day"+
```

or (for 51, but it's just fun)

```
"day Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur Sun"" "/.@=\0=
```

The requirement "not crash" is pretty lenient. This will just print "day" for invalid input – which is not a crash, so it should be allowed.

Answer (score 0):

## Cobra - 43

```
print if(0<n<8,(n%7)to DayOfWeek,'Invalid')
```

Answer (score 0):

## R, 61

```
a=format(Sys.Date()+0:15,"%A");a[grep("^M",a)[1]+0:6][scan()]
```

`format(Sys.Date()+0:15,"%A")` outputs the day of the week of today and the 15 following days. `grep("^M",a)[1]+0:6` is the index of the first monday in that sequence and the six following days.

Usage:

```
> a=format(Sys.Date()+0:15,"%A");a[grep("^M",a)[1]+0:6][scan()]
1: 7
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Sunday"
> a=format(Sys.Date()+0:15,"%A");a[grep("^M",a)[1]+0:6][scan()]
1: 4
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Thursday"
> a=format(Sys.Date()+0:15,"%A");a[grep("^M",a)[1]+0:6][scan()]
1: 2
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] "Tuesday"
> a=format(Sys.Date()+0:15,"%A");a[grep("^M",a)[1]+0:6][scan()]
1: 8
2: 
Read 1 item
[1] NA
```

Answer (score 0):

## CJam - 47 or 45

```
qi"Sun Mon Tues Wednes Thurs Fri Satur"S/="day"
```

Try it at http://cjam.aditsu.net/

If I can assume that the number is already on the stack, then the first 2 characters can be removed.

Answer (score 0):

### C# - 28

According to your reference solution, this should be valid.

It assumes the input is stored in the variable `i` and outputs "Sunday", "Monday", etc for 0, 1, etc respectively.

If `i` is out of bounds (below 0 or above 7), `i` will be output. (This is valid because the program doesn't crash)

```
Console.Write((DayOfWeek)i);
```

If you actually want a working function, here is one using 48 bytes:

```
string f(int i){return((DayOfWeek)i)+"";}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Python - <s>83</s> 76

```
from datetime import*
i=input()
if 0<i<8:print date(2013,7,i).strftime("%A")
```

July 2013 was the first month I found that had monday as its first day. Rest of this is quite self explanatory.

Comment: It's 82 bytes, don't count the trailing newline. You can use `from datetime import*` and `date` instead of `import datetime as d` and `d.date` (-1 byte), `input()` instead of `int(input)` (-5 bytes), and `1,1` instead of `2013,7` (-3 bytes).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions! Although "1,1" as "year,month" does not work; ValueError: year=1 is before 1900; the datetime strftime() methods require year >= 1900

Answer (score 0):

## Java 8, 48 chars

```
return n>0&n<8?DayOfWeek.of(n).name():"Invalid";
```

With java 8 comes new enum [DayOfWeek](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/DayOfWeek.html), that provides non locale dependent data.

For java 7 and older, this should work good too (76 chars):

```
return n<1|n>7?"Invalid":DateFormatSymbols.getInstance().getWeekdays()[n+1];
```

And locale fixed variant (90 chars):

```
return <1|n>7?"Invalid":DateFormatSymbols.getInstance(Locale.ENGLISH).getWeekdays()[n+1];
```

Answer (score 0):

### C, 81

Just for fun...

```
printf("%sday\n","Mon\0Tues\0Wednes\0Thurs\0Fri\0Satur\0Sun"+"  $)06:@"[n&7]-32);
```

Comment: What's "just for fun" about this answer?

Answer (score 0):

## Java

Uses local language:

```
return i<1||i>7?"Error":new DateFormatSymbols().getWeekdays()[i];
```

Comment: You can use only one | instead of || to save one character. Also good idea to create new instance, instead of calling getInstance(). It is shorter. But without specific locale, your output for 1 can be "sunday", not "monday" (locale en_US).

Answer (score 0):

### C, 117

Also just for fun...

```
d(n){for(char*p="\177MvT|WpF S\177oxh`a`t\026uze|d;n|eHrrspi\001d\001a\001y\001\n";
*p;p++)-*p++&1<<n-1&&putchar(*p);}
```

(I realize this isn't an obfuscation challenge. I just wanted to see how far a purely data-driven bit-test loop could be golfed.)

---

The un-golfed version:

```
void d(int n)
{
  char *p =
    "\177" "M"   "\166" "T"   "\174" "W"   "\160" "F"   "\040" "S"
    "\177" "o"   "\170" "h"   "\140" "a"   "\140" "t"   "\026" "u"
    "\172" "e"   "\174" "d"   "\073" "n"   "\174" "e"   "\110" "r"
    "\162" "s"   "\160" "i"   "\001" "d"   "\001" "a"   "\001" "y"
    "\001" "\n";

  for (; *p; p++)
    if (-(*(p++)) & (1<<(n-1)))
      putchar(*p);
}
```

Driver:

```
int main() { for (int n = 1; n <= 7; n++) d(n); }
```

Output:

```
Monday
Tuesday
Wednesday
Thursday
Friday
Saturday
Sunday
```

---

How it works:

- The character string consists of a pairs of bit-flags and output characters.
- The even indexes are the bit-flags ('\177', 'v', '|', 'p', ' ', etc.) — but they are stored in ones-complement form to minimize the number of nonprintable ASCII values, which are expensive because they have to be encoded in octal.
- The odd indexes are the output characters ('M', 'T', 'W', 'F', 'S', 'o', 'h', 'a', etc.).

Answer (score 0):

## Batch - 114 Bytes

```
@cmd/von/c"for %%a in (1Mon 2Tues 3Wednes 4Thur 5Fri 6Satur 7Sun)do @set a=%%a&if "!a:~0,1!"=="%1" echo !a:~1!day"
```

The first part `@cmd/von/c` is starting up a new cmd session - it uses the `/v` switch to enable delayed variable expansion, which saves adding in the lengthy `setLocal enableDelayedExpansion`. This way you only need to add the `@` symbol (to hide output) before the `cmd` command and in the middle of the for loop, instead of `@echo off` at the start of the script.

Answer (score 0):

## PHP - 32

Day is given as `$i`

```
<?echo date('l',(($i+4)*86400));
```

Answer (score 0):

## bash - 18

```
date +%A -d01010$1
```

Save it in a file, e.g. day.sh, then run

```
./day.sh 1 # output: Monday
./day.sh 2 # output: Tuesday
...
```

Comment: Try: save it in a file `script.sh` and run: `bash script.s 1`, it will output "Monday". `bash script.sh 2`, it will output "Tuesday" etc...

Comment: Because 2001-01-01 was Monday, but you can notice that the last number is precedeed by a $, so it's a parameter.

Answer (score 0):

### R, 37

The obligatory hack solution with R.

```
weekdays(as.Date((paste0("1/1/",n))))
```

where the input is first stored as variable `n`. Turning this into a named function would be longer:

```
d=function(n) weekdays(as.Date((paste0("1/1/",n))))
```

Answer (score 0):

### Javascript - 63

```
'0Mon0Tues0Wednes0Thurs0Fri0Satur0Sun'.split(0)[prompt()]+'day'
```

Comment: This doesn't handle invalid input correctly.

Comment: The spec doesn't stipulate invalid input handling, only that the program `doesn't crash`

Comment: I stand corrected.

Answer (score 0):

## C# - 30

Since the provided example doesn't actually output, neither does this. Also I'm assuming we don't *have* to have an error message if the value is below 1 or over 7.

```
((DayOfWeek)(n%7)).ToString();
```

For an error message (47):

```
n<1|n>7?"Error":((DayOfWeek)(n%7)).ToString();
```

The reason for the `%7` is because `DayOfWeek` begins with Sunday.

Small cheat: `DayOfWeek` is contained in the System namespace, so if `using System;` isn't specified elsewhere (usually always is), you'd need to replace `DayOfWeek` with `System.DayOfWeek` -- an additional 7 characters.